# how to copy byte array from c to java byte[] attribute directly with jni

Tags: java, android, c, arrays, java-native-interface

I am writing a C module with jni for android. 
my java class is

```
public class Payment {
    private static Payment payment = null;
    private long nativeObj;
    private byte[] sendBuffer;
    private byte[] recvBuffer;
    private byte[] msg;

    private Payment() {
        this.sendBuffer = new byte[1024];
        this.recvBuffer = new byte[1024];
        this.msg = new byte[1024];
    }

    public native void setArray();

 }
```

i want to fill byte arrays of Payment instance in c and i can not do it. 
what is the procedure of jni call for this purpose?

i get the field id of sendBuffer with

```
jclass thisClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
jfieldID sendId = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, thisClass, "sendBuffer", "[B");
```

but i can not figure out how to copy data from char[1024] to sendBuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this to copy data from C to java bytes array;

```
jint_Java_com_stack_overflow_copyBytes(JNIEnv *e, jclass obj, jlong p)
{
    jclass thisClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(e, obj);
    jfieldID sendId = (*env)->GetFieldID(e, thisClass, "sendBuffer", "[B");        
    jbyteArray bytes = (*e)->GetObjectField(e, obj, sendId)

    jbyte* b = (*e)->GetByteArrayElements(e, bytes, NULL);
    memcpy(myCBytes, b, len);
    (*e)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(e, bytes, b, 0);
}
```

Comment: i don't want to pass my instance attribute (byte[]) to native function!

Comment: @COP you can use `jbyteArray bytes = (*e)->GetObjectField(e, obj, sendId)`  to access the jbyteArray if you want.

Comment: @cleblanc It is sometimes best to refactor data copying and conversion operations from JNI code to Java code. Often, in such cases, the `native` methods would become `private` (and possibly `static`), being bridges to JNI rather than part of the class's public interface.